# How to make multiple routing on same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-routing

What I want to do is like Facebook profile page which is (facebook.com/username) , I'd like to do the same thing www.myapplication/username , is there any routing method ??

Answer (score 0):

To route to a profile page, you need a route with a RouteConstraint to check the validity of the username.  Your route must be the first route, and RegisterRoutes in Global.asax.cs should look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Profiles", // Route name
        "{username}", // URL
        new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }, // Parameters
        new { username = new MustBeUsername() }

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Then, you must create a RouteConstraint class which will check you database to confirm that the username submitted is valid:

```
using System; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Routing;  

namespace ExampleApp.Extensions 
{ 
    public class MustBeUsername : IRouteConstraint  
    { 
        public MustBeUsername() { }

        private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)    
        {      
            return (_db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == values[parameterName].ToString()).Count() > 0);
        }  
    } 
}
```

counsellorben

Comment: Thank you for your reply but what if I tried your code but with some modifications. I'm getting my user by Session so I had an Exception (null pointer) when it load at the first time and if I put if condition it will skip it won't go inside it again as the global.asax called once , please advise

Comment: If someone is accessing a profile, it generally is not the user who created the profile, so your Sessoin will not contain the correct information to validate your route.  The only way to check the validity of the route is through your User database.

Comment: Yes you are right on Facebook but I guess Twitter does it if you clicked on Profile you will get this link http://twitter.com/#!/YourUserName

Comment: The issue then is not the RouteConstraint to verify that you are going to a valid Profile page, but the rights assigned to the user who accesses the Profile page.  If it is the user accessing his/her own profile, then you can use Session to give the user edit rights.